# Delete a column from a Polars DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

Similar to pandas, I expected the following to work.

```
del df["col"]
```

However, the following error is raised:

```
AttributeError
Cell In[12], line 1
----> 1 del df["col"]

AttributeError: __delitem__
```

How can I delete a column from a polars DataFrame?

Answer (score 3):

The standard approach in Polars is to use [`pl.DataFrame.drop`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
df = df.drop("col")
```

where we can pass either a column name (as string) or a [column selector](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/selectors.html):

```
df = df.drop(polars.selectors.numeric())
```

In the example above, all numeric columns are dropped from `df`.

Moreover, in some circumstances it might be more natural to think about selecting certain columns. In this case, [`pl.DataFrame.select`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.select.html) would be more clear:

```
df = df.select(pl.all().exclude("col"))
```

Again, this could be combined with column selectors.

Comment: And note that if you're using the Lazy API, you basically never need to think about dropping; the optimizer will automatically drop columns as soon as they're not needed.